# Can np.ndarray be annotated with a custom dtype?

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting

We can create [custom dtypes](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) with record-like properties:

```
dt = np.dtype([('R','u1'), ('G','u1'), ('B','u1'), ('A','u1')])
```

We can [annotate the data type of an ndarray](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html) for type hinting:

```
numpy.typing.NDArray = numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[+ScalarType]]
```

However, I can't work out how to hint that an array is supposed to have a custom dtype, for instance `a: NDArray[dt]` results in Pylance complaining:

```
Declared return type, "ndarray[Any, dtype[Unknown]]", is partially unknown Pylance(reportUnknownVariableType)
Illegal type annotation: variable not allowed unless it is a type alias Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

I guess what I'm asking is if is possible to create a type from a dtype object, or what the +ScalarType means in `numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[+ScalarType]]`.

Comment: Which type checking mode do you run pylance in? Basic of strict?

Comment: I don't think there is any support for structured dtypes in the type system yet -- you are currently in bleeding edge typed numpy. I'm highly interested in this if you solve it.

Comment: Link for scalar types: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-built-in.  I assume that covers all the numeric dtypes, and maybe the string ones.  You are working with a `compound dtype`

Comment: @LudvigH Pylance is in strict mode; switching it to basic causes Pylance to no longer complain about the `partially unknown` type but using `dt` as a type is still `illegal`. Thanks for giving me the correct terminology of calling `dt` a compound dtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array with a compound dtype like this:

```
In [98]: dt = np.dtype([('R','u1'), ('G','u1'), ('B','u1'), ('A','u1')])
In [99]: arr = np.ones(3, dt)
In [100]: arr
Out[100]: 
array([(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1)],
      dtype=[('R', 'u1'), ('G', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1'), ('A', 'u1')])
```

The elements of this array of type, `np.void`

```
In [101]: type(arr[0])
Out[101]: numpy.void
In [102]: arr.dtype
Out[102]: dtype([('R', 'u1'), ('G', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1'), ('A', 'u1')])
```

Comment: Thanks! I did find this out later after some independent fiddling, but it's not ideal as `NDArray[np.void]` will match anything with a compound dtype. I suppose this answer and the comment on my question imply that there is (currently) no support for specifying a specific non-scalar dtype in numpy.